# Change the appbar title based on current screen bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to change the title of `SmallTopAppBar` based on what screen you navigate to. I get results printed out. But, when I assign this same result to `title` a global `var` it does not display.

```
var title = ""
LaunchedEffect(navController){
    navController.currentBackStackEntryFlow.collect{backStackEntry ->
        Log.d("App", backStackEntry.destination.route.toString())
        title = backStackEntry.destination.route.toString()
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            SmallTopAppBar(
                title = { Text(text = title)
```

**Clarity:** The `Log.d("App", backStackEntry.destination.route.toString())` does print out results, and it is dynamic coming from the navigation. But, for some unknown reason, this is not updated on the actual **UI**, *what am I missing here.*

**Troubleshooted:** `"$title"` does not work. I tried setting a title manually, `title = { Text(text = "Home") }` and this works, but, this isn't dynamic nor changing, stays the same all the time.

**EDIT:** It's inside a `@Composable`,

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Preview
@Composable
fun Main() {
    var title = "Home"
```

Comment: What do you mean by global var? Isn't `title` inside one of your Composable functions?

Comment: @Thracian, hi, thanks for reply. Yes, it is inside. Sorry.

Comment: Another question does this `LaunchedEffect(navController)` runs block each time you navigate to new route? It should only fire once because your key for LaunchedEffect `navController ` seems like it never changes

Comment: @Thracian, it keeps firing all the time, because, when I change navigation using bottom navigation between screens, there's actually a print out from `Log.d.`

Comment: Okay. Have you tried my answer, does it work?

Comment: @Thracian, not yet. I have an error trying to build now, because I tried installing `'com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.42'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you don't store value of title inside a remember and don't trigger a recomposition when it changes. When it recomposes again with "" String.

`var title by remember {mutableStateOf("")}` will make sure that it will be updated